# ORA-01882: timezone region not found in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Getting this error on trying to update an Oracle Connection suing Entity Framework from a ASP.Net MVC Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

> SQL Server Developer:
>   Edit this config file: C:\Program Files\sqldeveloper 3\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf then add this line anywhere in the file:

```
    AddVMOption -Duser.timezone="+02:00" (My time zone)
```

> Oracle Data Modeler
>   Edit this config file: C:\Program Files\datamodeler 3\datamodeler\bin\datamodeler.conf, then add this line anywhere in the file:

```
    AddVMOption -Duser.timezone="+02:00" (My time zone)
```

source [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/354169/Solving-ORA-timezone-region-not-found)

Comment: I  am trying to do Entity Framework database-first from Visual Studio and not connecting from SQL Developer

Comment: are you using ODP.NET to connect to oracle server? If not could you specify how the program connects to DB?

Comment: I am using ODP.Net driver in Visual Studio Wizard for creating an Entity Framework Model from Database

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/354169/Solving-ORA-timezone-region-not-found), you need to edit the config file that was installed.  it will either be `C:\Program Files\sqldeveloper 3\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf` or `C:\Program Files\datamodeler 3\datamodeler\bin\datamodeler.conf`

And add the following line:

```
    AddVMOption -Duser.timezone="+02:00"
```

Modified for your timezone, of course.

Comment: I  am trying to do Entity Framework database-first from Visual Studio and not connecting from SQL Developer